# Arguments in lambda expressions

Tags: haskell, lambda

In a book I encountered the following lambda expression

```
(λabc.cba)zz(λwv.w)
```

How should I interpret the arguments of (λabc.cba)? Are there two arguments

```
(zz)(λwv.w)
```

or are there three arguments

```
(z)(z)(λwv.w)
```

I suspect three arguments since normally one letter is used in Mathematics to denote a variable (unlike from in programming).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are there two arguments or are there three arguments?

**Three arguments**

If don't explicit add parentheses to `zz` as `(zz)`, the application associate to the left as below:

```
( ( (λabc.cba) z) z) (λwv.w)
```

It is equivalent to take three arguments.